# How to join addresses and shipment items to order_shipment collection in Magento?

Tags: magento, join, collections

I need to export a filtered collection of shipments with full address details and full shipment items details from Magento.

I get the (unfiltered) collection with:

```
/* @var Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Shipment_Collection $collection */
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->getCollection();
```

The object `$collection` offers two join functions, `join` and `joinAttribute`. `joinAttribute` is inherited from Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Collection_Abstract and is not implemented.

The address model is an EAV model, so with `join` I don't get the attributes of the address, only the entity id's.

Another solution would be to get the collection of all addresses and join it with the filtered set of shipments. The problem is then to get the collection of all shipments, because the code below returns an empty collection.

```
/* @var Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Address_Collection $collection */
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

How can I get a collection of shipments with full address details and all shipment items?

Comment: What do you want to filter the shipments by? Also, is there a reason why you want all of this done in a single query? Can't you just iterate over the collection and spin up additional requests to the database? It isn't ideal, but a it'll get the job done if you don't have a huge number of shipment objects.

Comment: @RudolphGottesheim I want to retrieve all shipments where incrementId > x. My current code iterates over the shipments collection, but I want to improve it.

Comment: I'm in a hurry right now, so I can just give you a quick hint.. Have a look at the `addAttributeToFilter()` or `addFieldToFilter()` methods (can't remember the exact name right now). If you can't find what you're looking for, just post another comment and I'll give you a longer/real answer.